# Colab notebooks are very large - how can I reduce their size?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab as my primary coding environment. I've noticed that some of my notebooks are very large (~100 MB), for example [this one](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SNVaJqYTu9gbg13TS9Edi5vQPWmMulnu?usp=sharing). Why is this? Is it because of the large pandas dataframes I've loaded? Or because of the `plotly express` figures? Or because of the neural networks I have created? I thought that when I end the colab notebook the used memory from the notebook would be deleted. How can I avoid such large files in the future (the space on my Google drive is getting small)? Can I select somewhere in the notebook memory to be freed?

I also wonder how to interpret the picture before: is my notebook only 2MB large but has access to 100MB of data on the drive or IS REALLY the notebook occupying 100MB on my drive, hence occupying a significant space >> 2MB? Tnx

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the file size by deleting the output of data frames, graphs, maps, etc. (by clicking on the icon below the Run button) and saving the file?

Comment: When the relevant file is executed, there will be a 100MB file created in the virtual environment that will disappear when the expiration date comes.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks for the comments! Regarding your 2nd comment: Let's say I have 14GB used of my available 15GB in Gdrive. Are this 100MB occupying some of these 14GB? Or should I not worry about this 100MB occupying valuable space in my Gdrive?
Regarding your 1st comment: I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't reduce the "storage used" statistic. Any other ideas?

Comment: To find out if the file is using the storage capacity, click on the storage capacity on the bottom left side of the Google drive management screen and you will see a list of files in descending order of storage capacity.

Comment: @r-beginners Yes, it was only after I saw in the management screen the huge storage of the colab notebooks that I decided to write this question here. But I still don't know how to reduce the storage